# If condition not working in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to classic ASP.  What is wrong with the code below: If condition error, don't get it.  Please help.

```
<select NAME="Priority" style="WIDTH:200px"  Id="Priority">
  <option value='0' <%= if(condition) then "selected" end%> 0 </option>
  <option value='1' <%= if(condition) then "selected" end%> 1 </option>
  <option value='2' <%= if(condition) then "selected" end%> 2 </option>
  <option value='3' <%= if(condition) then "selected" end%> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm *guessing* this is what you intended to post.

Comment: What did the original post, before editing, show??? Are you trying to select a given option based on the condition? Or, are you trying to show the word "selected" in the HTML output? Or, ... please give more detail about what you want to happen based on this code.

Answer (score 4):

Should be :

```
<% if condition then response.write("selected") %>
```

For more info see here:

http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/If_then_else.asp

Comment: Although this is correct [@EduardoMolteni approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8669602/692942) is my preferred approach to dealing with this type of conditional.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [in-line `if`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf) function (note I didn't say statement) in VBScript. So I always have this in my toolbox:

```vb
function iif(siONo, SiRetval, NoRetval )
    if SiONo then
        iif = SiRetval
    else
        iif = NoRetval
    end if
end function
```

Which allows you to do:

```
<option value='0' <%= iif(condition, "selected", "") %> 0 </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the select (Priority) is getting its data from a database then you could use a function.
Is the page updating or inserting?

```
<select NAME="Priority" style="WIDTH:200px"  Id="Priority">
<option value="0" <%= isSelected(Priority,"0") %>>0</option>
<option value="1" <%= isSelected(Priority,"1") %>>1</option>
<option value="2" <%= isSelected(Priority,"2") %>>2</option>
<option value="3" <%= isSelected(Priority,"3") %>>3</option>
</select>


    Function isSelected(x,y)
    if Cstr(x) = Cstr(y) then
        isSelected = "selected=""Selected"""
    else
        isSelected = ""
    end if
end Function
```

The item Priority would be a numeric field and have a default value assigned. Place the function snippet in a page that is used globally.

Comment: Similar but [@EduardoMolteni answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8669602/692942) is more generic approach.

Answer (score -1):

You were missing if in 'end if' and there was a extra closing tag missing in  after closing asp code block %>. Hope this works.

```
<select NAME="Priority" style="WIDTH:200px"  Id="Priority">
  <option value="0" <% if(condition) then Response.write("selected") end if %>>0</option>
  <option value="1" <% if(condition) then Response.write("selected") end if %>>1</option>
  <option value="2" <% if(condition) then Response.write("selected") end if %>>2</option>
  <option value="3" <% if(condition) then Response.write("selected") end if %>>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When calling an `If` in-line in Classic ASP you do not need the `End If`.