# Classic ASP - IF statement in a select drodown

Tags: html, asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could sort something out for me.

I have the following script

```
strInput = "<select name=""winner"">" &_
    "<option></option>" &_
    "<option value=""1"">1st</option>" &_
    "<option value=""2"">2nd</option>" &_
    "<option value=""3"">3rd</option>" &_
    "<option value=""4"">4th</option>" &_
"</select>"
```

How do i insert a 'if' statement into the options to check for a value and then select that option by default

```
if intVal = 1 then
    selected="selected"
End If
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If condition not working in classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663025/if-condition-not-working-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"<option value=""1"" " & iif(intVal = 1, " ""Selected"" ", " ") & ">1st</option>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
strInput = "<select name=""winner"">"
strInput = strInput &  "<option></option>"
strInput = strInput &  "<option value=""1"""
If intVal = 1 Then
    strInput = strInput &  " selected"
End If
strInput = strInput &  ">1st</option>"
strInput = strInput &  "<option value=""2"""
If intVal = 2 Then
    strInput = strInput &  " selected"
End If
strInput = strInput &  ">2st</option>"
strInput = strInput &  "<option value=""3"""
If intVal = 3 Then
    strInput = strInput &  " selected"
End If
strInput = strInput &  ">3st</option>"
strInput = strInput &  "<option value=""4"""
If intVal = 4 Then
    strInput = strInput &  " selected"
End If
strInput = strInput &  ">4st</option>"
strInput = strInput &  "</select>"
```

or

```
Function IsSelected(optionValue, defaultValue)
    If optionValue = defaultValue Then
        IsSelected = " selected"
    Else
        IsSelected = ""
    End If
End Function

strInput = "<select name=""winner"">" &_
    "<option></option>" &_
    "<option value=""1""" & IsSelected(1,intVal) & ">1st</option>" &_
    "<option value=""2""" & IsSelected(2,intVal) & ">2nd</option>" &_
    "<option value=""3""" & IsSelected(3,intVal) & ">3rd</option>" &_
    "<option value=""4""" & IsSelected(4,intVal) & ">4th</option>" &_
"</select>"
```